# Recursion on Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I need some help in understanding the processing that happens here, so let´s say I call `fib(5)` I want the fibonacci  5, which is 8. But my brain in trying to understand the algorithm says it´s not. This is how i (wrongly) think:

```
return fib(4) + fib(3) // Stack frame 1
return fib(3) + fib(1) // Stack frame 2
```

now cause x is 1 `fib(1)`, the conditional statement `if x == 0 or x == 1:` causes the recursion to end. Which according to my logic would become 3+1+4+3. Please correct my faulty logic.

```
def fib(x):
    """assumes x an int >= 0
       returns Fibonacci of x"""
    assert type(x) == int and x >= 0
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
```

Comment: Just write down on a paper the first call and replace each recursive calls of the function with the valid return statement.
What you probably don't understand is that `return fib(x - 1) + fib( x - 2)` calls twice your fib function, one with **parameter** x = **current** x decremented once, and the other decremented twice. You should also probably look into function arguments again, since this is a typical misunderstanding when using functions (at first).

Comment: Just put some print statement in your function and run it to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full expansion of what happens:

```
fib(5) expands to fib(4)+fib(3)
  fib(4) expands to fib(3)+fib(2)
    fib(3) expands to fib(2)+fib(1)
      fib(2) expands to fib(1)+fib(0)
        fib(1) evaluates to 1
        fib(0) evaluates to 1
      fib(1) evaluates to 1
    fib(2) expands to fib(1)+fib(0)
      fib(1) evaluates to 1
      fib(0) evaluates to 1
  fib(3) expands to fib(2)+fib(1)
    fib(2) expands to fib(1)+fib(0)
      fib(1) evaluates to 1
      fib(0) evaluates to 1
    fib(1) evaluates to 1
```

If you count the ones, you get 8 as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For all `x` greater than 1, the `fib` function calls itself *twice*:

1. `fib(5)` becomes `fib(4) + fib(3)`
2. and expands to `(fib(3) + fib(2)) + (fib(2) + fib(1))`
3. and expands to `((fib(2) + fib(1)) + (fib(1) + fib(0))) + ((fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1)`
4. expands to `(((fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1) + (1 + 1)) + ((1 + 1) + 1)`
5. expands to `(((1 + 1) + 1) + (1 + 1)) + ((1 + 1) + 1)`

which sums up to `8`.